# Dual Booting on Chromebook

Tags: 12.04, unity

I recently managed to dual-boot my Acer C720 Chromebook with Ubuntu Unity. However, unlike the standard desktops that I've seen via tutorials, etc., Unity comes preloaded with Firefox, Libre tools, and most importantly the Software Center. Mine came with none of those things. While I succeeded in installing Firefox, when I attempted to install the software center, I was told that the software could not be located. Any ideas on how to fix this? Here are the commands I ran in my attempt to get my desktop up to snuff:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo apt-get install software-center*
sudo apt-get install firefox
```

Answer (score 0):

You seem to have empty /etc/apt/sources.list. That happens if you do some unusual installation. Check that it contains both restricted and universe lines.